# How does a client interact with a contract already in the blockchain?

Tags: mining, clients, contract-invocation

I am looking for someone to help clarify the 'stacktrace' of interactions that occur when a client interacts with a smart contract.

Clearly, one has to submit a transaction to a miner, who then has to locate the contract by address (by using his/her own local copy of the blockchain?), and complete the computation set out in the contract.

Is the entire contract then re-written once again into the blockchain with the outputs representing the output of the computation that has taken place?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed the miner locates a contract by using their local copy of the blockchain.

> Is the entire contract then re-written once again into the blockchain with the outputs representing the output of the computation that has taken place?

Contracts are immutable.  But each contract can have a ["hard disk"](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/1232/42), called storage, and that's where the outputs of computations can be written.

Technically:

The web3.js Javascript API [Contract Methods](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#contract-methods) are a way to interact with contracts.

[JSON-RPC](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC) is a lower-level way of interacting with contracts.

Comment: Ok thanks - is the storage located within the original block in which the contract was mined?

Comment: Kind of, it's via pointers to trees.  Each block has a "state root" which contains accounts.  Each account has a "storage root".  Overview at http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/268/ethereum-block-architecture

Comment: Fantastic links & description with pictures. +1