# Is the cost of updating storage different than the cost of adding to storage?

Tags: contract-development, gas, evm, opcode

Do these have a separate cost?

```
sstore(1, 10) # first time adding a value to storage with this key
sstore(1, 20) # changing the value in storage.
```

I looked for a list of gas costs / opcodes, and the only one I could find (https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1m89CVujrQe5LAFJ8-YAUCcNK950dUzMQPMJBxRtGCqs/edit#gid=0) is a year old. It seems to say that modifying storage is cheaper, but I'm not sure if these values are outdated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, [using storage has different gas costs](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/1711/42):

> 20,000 gas when a value is set
> to non-zero from zero; 5,000 gas when writing to existing storage or
> setting a value to zero; and a [15,000 gas refund](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/859/42) when a non-zero value
> is set to zero.

The [Yellow Paper](https://github.com/ethereum/yellowpaper) is the underlying source.

[EIP-2200](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-2200.md) has further explanations.

Related question: [Does an SSTORE where the new value is the same as the existing value cost gas?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/90318/does-an-sstore-where-the-new-value-is-the-same-as-the-existing-value-cost-gas)

Comment: Due to [EIP-3529](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-3529), I don't think that this answer is up to date anymore. In particular, the gas refund is much lower than 15,000 now.

Comment: @PaulRazvanBerg Agree, there's been plenty of changes to gas costs. I recall a related question I updated more than a year ago with the different EIPs, I'll try to find. Another approach is I could put a bounty here to try to elicit a well-written answer. Precise answer to this question could keep changing as the EVM evolves, so attracting more views here might not be best.