# Does an SSTORE where the new value is the same as the existing value cost gas?

Tags: contract-development, gas, evm

For example (in Vyper):

```
@external
def foo(bar: uint256):
  self.baz = bar

foo(3)
foo(3) # Is the gas cost here still 5000?
```

Is it better to do this instead?

```
def foo(bar: uint256):
  if self.baz != bar: # Will this check save gas from unnecessary SSTORE's
      self.baz = bar
```

Comment: Watch out from counting on the 200 gas assumption provided in the answer that you've accepted. I believe that it may apply to older EVM versions (prior Istanbul or something like that), where SLOAD used to cost 200 gas. In the current version, SLOAD costs 800 gas, so I have a reason to suspect that the 200 gas in your specific case may also have changed to 800 gas (as measured in my test example).

Comment: Agree with @goodvibration, his answer is correct (not @technicallyty).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following test implies that the cost of storing the same value is 800 gas units:

**Solidity Contract:**

```
pragma solidity 0.6.12;

contract MyContract {
    uint256 public gasUsed;
    uint256 public storageSlot;
    function func(uint256 x) public {
        storageSlot = x;
        uint256 gasLeft = gasleft();
        storageSlot = x;
        gasUsed = gasLeft - gasleft();
    }
}
```

**Truffle 5.x Test:**

```
const MyContract = artifacts.require("MyContract");

contract("MyContract", accounts => {
    it("test", async () => {
        const myContract = await MyContract.new();
        for (let x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
            await myContract.func(x);
            const gasUsed = await myContract.gasUsed();
            console.log(gasUsed.toString());
        }
    });
});
```

The printout is 816 for every iteration.

Assuming that the `gasleft()` operation in the last line of the contract function spends 16 gas units, the cost of storing the same value appears to be 800 gas units.

Comment: Interesting. The EVM for this contract may need to be checked, or post as a question. The current Geth source indicates 200 gas.

Comment: @eth: Yeah, I'm about to post a question on that.

Comment: I think calling the gasLeft() function costs extra gas.

Comment: @DylanKerler: Maybe, but I doubt that it costs 616 gas.

Comment: @eth: According to [this answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/90345/16043), the cost is actually 800 gas at this point. Any idea what is the correct answer for the current EVM version (since you seem to have agreed with the accepted answer here)? Thanks.

Comment: You're right I'm updating my answer...  Sorry for delay.  Feel free to comment on it if I might be mistaken.  (I can't take my upvote on the other answer back.)

Comment: I'm coming back to this again after digging into the opcodes. Yes, it seems this is 800 gas but `gasLeft()` is not 16 gas. gasLeft() (GAS) is 2 gas. The initial call does a GAS (2 gas), PUSH1 (3 gas) and MSTORE (3 gas) so 8 gas in total. Then before the SUB it does PUSH1 (3 gas) and an MLOAD (3 gas) which totals to 14 gas. Then it does the final call of GAS (2 gas) so the total is 16 gas overhead in addition to the 800 gas.

Answer (score 5):

Thank you to the answers by @technicallyty and @goodvibration, and @goodvibration's continuation and approach is correct.

### Yes, storing the same value costs 800 gas.

[EIP-2200](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-2200.md) and the relevant code is actually the next function [**gasSStoreEIP2200**](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/00d10e610f9fef56b5ee9c27f7fe7c842eba2e9b/core/vm/gas_table.go#L165-L192)

More precisely the code:

```
if current == value { // noop (1)
    return params.SloadGasEIP2200, nil
}
```

which is [commented](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/00d10e610f9fef56b5ee9c27f7fe7c842eba2e9b/core/vm/gas_table.go#L166) as

```
// 1. If current value equals new value (this is a no-op), SLOAD_GAS is deducted.
```

And [**SloadGasEIP2200**](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/00d10e610f9fef56b5ee9c27f7fe7c842eba2e9b/params/protocol_params.go#L89) is 800:

```
SloadGasEIP2200 uint64 = 800  // Cost of SLOAD after EIP 2200 (part of Istanbul)
```

---

#### More information

Here are the full comments on `gasSStoreEIP2200` based on EIP-2200:

```
// 0. If *gasleft* is less than or equal to 2300, fail the current call.
// 1. If current value equals new value (this is a no-op), SLOAD_GAS is deducted.
// 2. If current value does not equal new value:
//   2.1. If original value equals current value (this storage slot has not been changed by the current execution context):
//     2.1.1. If original value is 0, SSTORE_SET_GAS (20K) gas is deducted.
//     2.1.2. Otherwise, SSTORE_RESET_GAS gas is deducted. If new value is 0, add SSTORE_CLEARS_SCHEDULE to refund counter.
//   2.2. If original value does not equal current value (this storage slot is dirty), SLOAD_GAS gas is deducted. Apply both of the following clauses:
//     2.2.1. If original value is not 0:
//       2.2.1.1. If current value is 0 (also means that new value is not 0), subtract SSTORE_CLEARS_SCHEDULE gas from refund counter.
//       2.2.1.2. If new value is 0 (also means that current value is not 0), add SSTORE_CLEARS_SCHEDULE gas to refund counter.
//     2.2.2. If original value equals new value (this storage slot is reset):
//       2.2.2.1. If original value is 0, add SSTORE_SET_GAS - SLOAD_GAS to refund counter.
//       2.2.2.2. Otherwise, add SSTORE_RESET_GAS - SLOAD_GAS gas to refund counter.
```

`gasSStoreEIP2200` is the current function, and `gasSStore` is for historical.
(As @MrClottom says in [his answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/90339/gas-cost-of-setting-a-state-variable-to-the-same-value): "When a new node syncs and verifies all transactions it also has to be able to understand old consensus rules...")

Original answer below was missing EIP-2200 and was based on `gasSStore`.

> The [Geth source code (master branch Nov
> 2020)](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/ebb9591c4d860e85fe1a015e6c9d7e85b7500b9a/core/vm/gas_table.go#L120-L137)
> and
> [EIP-1283](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-1283.md)
> state:
>
> // The new gas metering is based on net gas costs (EIP-1283):   //  //
>
> 1. If current value equals new value (this is a no-op), 200 gas is deducted.  // 2. If current value does not equal new value     //   2.1.
>    If original value equals current value (this storage slot has not been
>    changed by the current execution context)     //     2.1.1. If original
>    value is 0, 20000 gas is deducted.    //     2.1.2. Otherwise, 5000 gas
>    is deducted. If new value is 0, add 15000 gas to refund counter.  //
>    2.2. If original value does not equal current value (this storage slot is dirty), 200 gas is deducted. Apply both of the following
>    clauses.  //    2.2.1. If original value is not 0     //       2.2.1.1.
>    If current value is 0 (also means that new value is not 0), remove
>    15000 gas from refund counter. We can prove that refund counter will
>    never go below 0.     //       2.2.1.2. If new value is 0 (also means
>    that current value is not 0), add 15000 gas to refund counter.    //
>    2.2.2. If original value equals new value (this storage slot is reset)    //       2.2.2.1. If original value is 0, add 19800 gas to refund
>    counter.  //       2.2.2.2. Otherwise, add 4800 gas to refund counter.
>    value := common.Hash(y.Bytes32())   if current == value { // noop (1)
>    return params.NetSstoreNoopGas, nil     }

Answer (score 3):

The gas cost would be 200. There is actually a comment in the source code of Geth referring to this exact behavior. In `protocol_params.go` on line 46 we see the following line of code:

`NetSstoreNoopGas  uint64 = 200   // Once per SSTORE operation if the value doesn't change.`

Source: https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/params/protocol_params.go

Comment: do you know if this is true across all clients? This answers for Geth, though theoretically other clients could be different, no?

Comment: @TheRenaissance The correct answer is by goodvibration.  All clients have to implement the same gas cost, they have to be in consensus, otherwise there would be multiple blockchains... One client can't charge you differently from another client: everyone has to agree how much you charged, how much you paid, how much funds you have left :)

Comment: @eth Thanks for the answer - I agree that opcodes have one standard price across clients, but thought that this might be a gray zone, and different clients might handle it differently.