# SLOAD costs 800 gas - how is it possible?

Tags: solidity, gas, gas-price, optimization, solidity-0.7.x

I've got a very simple contract. It narrows down and measures cost of loading a storage variable:

```
pragma solidity ^0.7.6;
contract Bench {
    
    uint256 public data;
    
    function increment() public {
        uint256 gasUsed = gasleft();
        uint256 dataLocal = data;
        gasUsed -= gasleft();
        dataLocal += gasUsed;
        data = dataLocal;
    }
    
}
```

It generates an unsurprising assembly:

```
(...)
      GAS           gasleft()
      PUSH 0            uint256 dataLocal
      SLOAD             data
      SWAP1             uint256 gasUsed = gasleft()
      SWAP2             uint256 gasUsed = gasleft()
      POP           
      GAS           gasleft()
(...)
```

The measured gas usage according to [the yellow paper](https://ethereum.github.io/yellowpaper/paper.pdf?) should be 213:

```
PUSH    - 3
SLOAD   - 200
SWAP1   - 3
SWAP2   - 3
POP     - 2
GAS     - 2
```

A simple Remix test shows the measured gas:

```
    function checkFailure() public {
        Bench bench = new Bench();
        bench.increment();
        Assert.equal(bench.data(), 0, "GAS USED");
    }
```

The printed result is 813, exactly 600 more than expected. Why? How to reduce that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Gas cost of setting a state-variable to the same value](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/90339/gas-cost-of-setting-a-state-variable-to-the-same-value)

Comment: No, the other question is about SSTORE. Some SSTORE operations happen to have the same cost as SLOAD, but that's a far stretch.

Comment: Ahhh, you're right. Funny enough though, the answer to that other question is exactly the same (and the gas-measurement in your question is almost the same as the gas-measurement in the other question).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[EIP-1884](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1884) (included in the [Istanbul](https://ethereum.org/en/history/) hard fork) changed the cost of an `SLOAD` from `200` to `800`, which explains why you are seeing exactly `600` more than expected.

It looks like the [yellow paper](https://ethereum.github.io/yellowpaper/paper.pdf?) has not been updated to reflect this change.

Edit: I have [opened a PR](https://github.com/ethereum/yellowpaper/pull/783) on the yellow paper repository to resolve this issue.

Comment: Nice catch, Shane.

Comment: @RobHitchens: Almost the exact same question was answered [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/90345/16043) a while back.

Comment: And also [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/90337/16043), by @eth himself (or herself).