# What does web3.eth.getStorageAt() return?

Tags: web3js, storage, get-storage-at

I want to know how this works: `web3.eth.getStorageAt(addressHexString, position [, defaultBlock] [, callback])`

What data we can store at any address and how? And what will this eth API return?

Comment: Related: http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6397/how-do-i-get-the-storage-indices-keys

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Each contract consists of a EVM bytecode handling the execution and a storage to save the state of the contract. This is a low level function to get the state of the contract's storage. The storage is essentially a key/value store.
The function returns the value the contracts storage has at a certain position.

Refer to the [GitHub wiki pages](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethgetstorageat).

More on storage [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/1711/264).

Answer (score 1):

As of version `1.0` of `web3.js`, the [`web3.utils.hexToAscii`](http://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-utils.html#hextoascii) function should be used. Correct syntax:

```
web3.eth.getStorageAt('/* Contract Address */', 0).then(result => {
  console.log(web3.utils.hexToAscii(result));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

for instance if you look at [this](https://github.com/lexansoft/etherid.org/blob/master/solidity/etherid.sol) contract source and you type this in geth:

```
web3.toAscii(web3.eth.getStorageAt("0x3589d05a1ec4Af9f65b0E5554e645707775Ee43C",1))
```

it returned the following

```
"\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00WEEDMAPS"
```

Comment: Would you be able to also provide an example for getting the address of a dynamic array? i've tried with web3.sha3("0x01") to calculate the address but can't figure it out.