# What should be the input for getStorageAt function in web3 js?

Tags: web3js, accounts, addresses, storage, get-storage-at

I am trying to trace history of transactions in ethereum. I am using a function called getStorageAt(). Now what should be the input to this function, a contract address or account address(account no)?

Answer (score 3):

https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethgetstorageat

```
web3.eth.getStorageAt(addressHexString, position ...
```

For `addressHexString` you will want a contract address, since random addresses are unlikely to have any values in storage.

For `position`, see
[How do I get the storage indices/keys?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6397/how-do-i-get-the-storage-indices-keys)