# What is the significance of memory keyword in this example

Tags: solidity

```
contract sample {
     uint32 count;

     struct example {
         uint32 value ;
     }
     mapping(uint32=example) mapper;    
     event trackInt(uint32);
     event trackObj(uint32);

     function test() {
         example memory  obj;
         obj.value = count +1;
         mapper[count]=obj;
         count++;
         trackObj(obj.value);
         trackInt(count);

     }

     function getCount() returns (uint32) {
         return count;        
     }

     function get(uint32 id) returns (uint32) {

         example obj = mapper[id-1];
         return obj.value;
     }
}
```

Even after calling the `test()` function several times, I am able to retrieve the details in the struct even though `obj` is of type memory . Could someone clarify how it works?

Answer (score 2):

Variables declared with `memory` keyword is only accessible during contract execution. Once execution is finished, it's contents are discarded.

In your program, you are creating a temporary struct variable using `memory` keyword named `obj`. This variable named `obj` exists during the execution of the contract and then get destroyed.

You are able to retrieve values because your variables `count` and mapping `mapper` both are stored as persistent i.e `storage` type variable and you are getting that data.

To know more about different type of variable storage, [check this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/23720/usage-of-memory-storage-and-stack-areas-in-evm).

Answer (score 1):

> Even after calling test() function several times ...

As far as I understand,

every time you call the  `test()` function you create a *example struct* type data object called *obj* temporarily in the memory and its then stored in the storage with the mapping *mapper*.

So every time you call the `test()` there is a obj of type *example*.

> the details in the struct

A [struct](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/types.html#structs) is a user defined new data type. What do you try to refer by ***the*** details in **the** struct? The struct you defined is not a storage/memory variable or constant value to refer so. It's just you are defining a data type. So whenever you refer as obj, its referred to the temporary example struct type object that is created in the memory with the respective function call.