# Switching from 'storage' to 'memory' increases the gas-cost

Tags: solidity, gas, storage, memory

I've read several related answers and blog posts, all of them suggesting that for the sake of reading complex state variables (i.e., arrays and structures), one should always prefer declaring the local variable used for this purpose as `memory` rather than as `storage`:

- [Ethereum SE Answer #1](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/27487)
- [Ethereum SE Answer #2](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/23722)
- [Ethereum SE Answer #3](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/1711)
- [Blog Post](https://medium.com/coinmonks/ethereum-solidity-memory-vs-storage-which-to-use-in-local-functions-72b593c3703a)

I've conducted several tests, performing `let response = await someTransaction()` and then recording the value of `response.receipt.gasUsed`. All of these tests have unanimously shown that declaring the local variable as `memory` yields a higher gas-consumption than declaring it as `storage`.

Here is a very simple Truffle test which illustrates this:

**Contract:**

```
pragma solidity 0.4.25;

contract MyContract {
    struct Record {
        bool valid;
        uint val1;
        uint val2;
        uint val3;
    }

    mapping(uint => Record) public table;

    uint public count;

    function insert(uint key, uint val1, uint val2, uint val3) external {
        Record storage record = table[key];
        if (record.valid == false) {
            record.valid = true;
            record.val1 = val1;
            record.val2 = val2;
            record.val3 = val3;
            count += 1;
        }
    }

    function storage_remove(uint[] keys) external {
        for (uint i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
            Record storage record = table[keys[i]];
            if (record.valid == true) {
                delete table[keys[i]];
                count -= 1;
            }
        }
    }

    function memory_remove(uint[] keys) external {
        for (uint i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
            Record memory record = table[keys[i]];
            if (record.valid == true) {
                delete table[keys[i]];
                count -= 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Test:**

```
contract("MyContractTest", function() {
    const keys = [...Array(10).keys()];

    it("storage_remove gas consumption", async function() {
        const myContract = await artifacts.require("MyContract").new();
        for (let key of keys)
            await myContract.insert(key, key, key, key);
        const response = await myContract.storage_remove(keys);
        console.log(response.receipt.gasUsed);
    });

    it("memory_remove gas consumption", async function() {
        const myContract = await artifacts.require("MyContract").new();
        for (let key of keys)
            await myContract.insert(key, key, key, key);
        const response = await myContract.memory_remove(keys);
        console.log(response.receipt.gasUsed);
    });
});
```

**Results:**

```
Contract: MyContractTest storage_remove gas consumption: 142257
Contract: MyContractTest memory_remove gas consumption: 145976
```

**Side Note:**

The above is essentially a comparison between:

- The gas cost of reading `record.valid` using `storage record`
- The gas cost of reading `record.valid` using `memory record`

So what course of action should I take - use `memory` as suggested everywhere, or use `storage` which has proved to be less expensive?

Thank you!

Comment: When assigning a `storage` reference data to a `memory` referenced variable, we are copying data from `storage` to `memory`. New memory is allocated. That's why you are getting this.

Comment: @MaheshRajput: Thank you. That was my initial thought, out of a "naive" approach I suppose (kinda like, comparing `storage vs memory` to `by reference vs by value` from C/C++). However, none of the posts that I've read mentioned anything about this, so I tend to think that this type of comparison between the block-chain and "traditional" systems is incorrect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you declare the variable as memory, you'll have to pay extra gas for reserving the memory and more important, you'll also have to SLOAD the complete record, which in your case will be 4 SLOAD operations (4x200 gas). Later in your code, you profit from the cheap MLOAD, but you'll need to access a field more than 4 times, so the 4 SLOADs before are paying off.

In the case with variable declared with storage, you have no additional costs for reserving the memory and you are not preloading from storage. You'll have a single SLOAD only, which is cheaper. However, if you would have more than 4 field accesses, your gas costs would soon exceed the costs of the variant with the memory modifer.

Hence, there is no universal solution for this. It depends on the circumstances.

Finally, this optimization-task is something that can and should be done by the compiler. I hope to see this soon in solc.

**EDIT**
With EIP-1884 SLOAD now costs 800 gas and no more 200 (https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1884) – thanks to 70ny for the pointer

Comment: So `storage` wins here because there is only 1 access (`record.valid`)? 4 would lead to a tie, and 5 or more would turn the odds in favor of `memory`? Reason I'm asking is that I've also tried a case with more than 1 access (though I can't remember if it was 3, 4 or 5 accesses).

Comment: Yes. It's roughly like this. Try adding additional field reads, then at a point with >4 of them, you'll notice the difference.

Comment: OK, this is a great answer, thank you very much for disassembling it for me :)

Comment: With EIP-1884 `SLOAD` now costs `800` gas and no more `200` (ref: https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1884 )