# Unable to resolve TypeError

Tags: solidity, addresses

I'm looking to ensure that an address is not the 0 address and with the update to 0.5.0 I am running into a TypeError `Operator != not compatible with types contract GeneScienceInterface and address payable`

```
function unpause() public onlyCEO whenPaused {
        require(geneScience != address(0));

        super.unpause();
    }
```

Comment: Can you also add how you are declaring `geneScience`, because I'm not getting any error while comparing `address(0)` to regular address variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should work if `geneScience` is cast as an `address`. Since it doesn't work for you, I suspect it's a `contract`, which means you can't compare it to an `address`.

You can resolve that by using the address property of the contract.

```
require(address(geneScience) != address(0));
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Funny, I've been doing this for quite some time now, and I wasn't aware of the `myContract.address` option, i.e., have always used `address(myContract)`, which I assume is identical...? Or is this a Solidity 0.5.x feature?

Comment: Good catch. You're right about the syntax. I edited my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Accidentally confused it with web3.js syntax I presume?

Comment: Unrelated: would you be able to refer to my question at https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/66382/16043?