# Why cryptokitties uses storage instead of memory?

Tags: solidity, storage, memory, cryptokitties

There are a lot of explainations of storage and memory out there like [this question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/17964/why-are-local-variables-allocated-to-storage-instead-of-memory) or [this question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1232/difference-between-memory-and-storage). But I'm wondering why cryptokitties for example uses storage instead of memory in many functions. In this case the `auction` is not modified. Wouldn't it be cheaper to use memory here?

```
function _bid(uint256 _tokenId, uint256 _bidAmount) internal returns (uint256) {

    Auction storage auction = _getAuctionByTokenId(_tokenId);
    require(_isOnAuction(auction));

    uint256 price = _currentPrice(auction);
    require(_bidAmount >= price);

    address seller = auction.seller;
    _removeAuction(_tokenId);

    // Transfer proceeds to seller (if there are any!)
    if (price > 0) {
       ...
        uint256 auctioneerCut = _computeCut(price);
        uint256 sellerProceeds = price - auctioneerCut;
        // Ether transfer
        seller.transfer(sellerProceeds);
    }

    emit AuctionSuccessful(_tokenId, price, msg.sender);
    return price;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because is not creating a new object but is a storage pointer. `_getAuctionByTokenId` most probably would read something in the contract storage.

Assume this example

```
contract MyContract {
    struct myStruct {
        address id;
    }
    mapping(address => myStruct) myMapping;

    function doSomeStuff(address _tokenId) public view returns(address) {    
        myStruct storage myObj = myMapping[_tokenId];

        return myObj.id;
    }   
}
```

`myObj` is not a new object but a pointer to a storage location already stored inside my contract. If I remove the `storage` keyword I would get the following warning:

> Warning: Variable is declared as a storage pointer. Use an explicit
>   "storage" keyword to silence this warning.

Answer (score 2):

It's cheaper to use `storage`, because it just creates a pointer. If you were to use `memory`, the function would essentially have to create a copy of the `Auction`, which would then be discarded at the end of the function.

They did it because there is no manipulation of `auction`, if they wanted to modify it somehow, but not changed the stored value, *then* it would be better to use `memory`.

I just read [this article on Medium](https://medium.com/coinmonks/solidity-bits-storage-vs-memory-a54a650ea4ff) which clearly describes the difference between the two.