# How to initialize a new struct with an empty mapping?

Tags: mapping, struct

For expl.

```
mapping(uint => Test) tests;

struct Test {
    uint id;
    mapping(address => uint) votes;
}
function newTest() public {
    test[0] = Test(0, <EMPTY_MAPPING>)
}
```

Comment: Asked a very similar question [before](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/62058/how-to-initialise-a-mapping-of-a-struct-inside-a-function/62059#62059).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can rewrite your code like this:

```
tests[0] = Test({
  id: 0
});
```

Solidity will make `votes` an empty mapping by default. Btw, there's also a typo in your code: should be `tests[0]` instead of `test[0]`.

Comment: Wrote that in Stackexchange instead of int he IDE. Thanks Paul that'll do it, I could not find the question you asked earlier.

Comment: This no longer works in newer versions of solidity, this is how it should be done now:
`Test storage test = tests[0];   test.id = 0;`