# The cost of using Ethereum as a reference database

Tags: gas, storage, gas-price

As stated in the documentation there are 3 types of storage in the Ethereum VM (EVM) The storage, the memory, and the stack

> Each account has a data area called storage, which is persistent
>   between function calls and transactions. Storage is a key-value store
>   that maps 256-bit words to 256-bit words. It is not possible to
>   enumerate storage from within a contract and it is **comparatively
>   costly to read, and even more to modify storage**. A contract can
>   neither read nor write to any storage apart from its own.

Let's say I want to store key-values pairs of millions of records e.g cars and owners, does this mean it will be extremely costly to do so ? 
Or the concept of storage is totally different of what I'm looking for ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is yes, it is presently extremely costly. And, yes, storage is what you're looking for. Storage is the [only persistent mechanism](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1232/difference-between-memory-and-storage).

Suppose each car is identified using a four-byte identifier (up to 4B cars) and each owner by a five-byte identifier (up to 1T people). Ignoring overhead for storing a sparse dataset, you're still looking at roughly 9 bytes per vehicle or ~9 MB for a million records. According to [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/872/what-is-the-cost-to-store-1kb-10kb-100kb-worth-of-data-into-the-ethereum-block), you're looking at around 640M gas which isn't going to be cheap. And directly using key-value storage is 20K of gas per write.

If you're using this to tokenization of physical objects like cars or houses, the per-unit cost is probably quite affordable: adding an extra $1 of overhead to a $10K sale is a percent of a percent.

Depending on your application, there might be other ways (including non-blockchain) solutions that are better suited to your situation.

Comment: What if I want to implement a smart contract that tracks the ownership of small goods like shoes, clothes, any other small belongings, even let's say smallest things like plastic bottles

Answer (score 0):

[This article](https://blockgeeks.com/guides/ethereum-gas-step-by-step-guide/) summarizes all what is needed to be know about Gas

> As explained in the introduction, Gas is a unit that measures the
>   amount of computational effort that it will take to execute certain
>   operations.
>
> Most of the smart contracts that run in the EVM are coded using
>   Solidity (Ethereum is planning to move on to Viper from Solidity in
>   the future).  Each and every line of code in Solidity requires a
>   certain amount of gas to be executed.