# How to Properly use "Memory" After Function Parameters

Tags: solidity, remix

I have a question about writing functions in Solidity - I am trying to create an array of dog structs but I can't seem to get the function declaration correctly:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.1;

contract MyContract {
    struct dog {
        string name;
        string ownername;
        int8 age;
    }
    dog[3] dogarray = dog(3);
    function setIndex(int index, string name, string ownername memory, int8 age) public {
        dogarray[index].name = name;
        dogarray[index].ownername = ownername;
        dogarray[index].age = age;
    }
    
}
```

I am getting the error `contracts/MyContract.sol:11:64: ParserError: Expected ',' but got 'memory' function setIndex(int index, string name, string ownername memory, int8 age memory) public { ^----^` and I have tried putting memory after all the parameters and after some of the parameters (like I did above) but the error message persists.

When do we use the keyword `memory`? From what I understand, `memory` just means temporary storage (equivalent to the stack?) and `storage` means more permanent storage (heap?). I have seen functions being written without it and with it, so I just want to know if it is optional and when to and when not to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Update 1: You have to write the argument like: `string memory ownername`.
- Update 2: Use **uint256** for indexing variables in arrays.
- Update 3: You don't need to initialize the `dogarray`

Here the the updated code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.1;

contract MyContract {
    struct dog {
        string name;
        string ownername;
        int8 age;
    }

    dog[3] dogarray;

    function setIndex(
        uint256 index,
        string memory name,
        string memory ownername,
        int8 age
    ) public {
        dogarray[index].name = name;
        dogarray[index].ownername = ownername;
        dogarray[index].age = age;
    }
}
```

Check [difference-between-memory-and-storage](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1232/difference-between-memory-and-storage).