# Does the 10,000 refund apply to booleans too?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, gas, gas-refund

I understand from this [thread](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/40944/how-can-i-estimate-price-of-data-storage) that you're refunded up to 10,000 gas when setting a value to 0.

Does this also apply to boolean values? That is, going from `true` to `false`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it does. To the EVM, setting a `bool` to `false` is equivalent to setting a `uint` to `0` in that it clears a storage slot.

You can try it out with the code below. In this contract, the following transaction costs are:

`setBool()` = 41705

`setUint()` = 41474

`unsetBool()` = 13386

`unsetUint()` = 13204

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.10;

contract RefundTest {

    bool public boolGasTest;
    uint256 public uintGasTest;

    function unsetBool() public {
        boolGasTest = false;
    }

    function setBool() public {
        boolGasTest = true;
    }

    function unsetUint() public {
        uintGasTest = 0;
    }

    function setUint() public {
        uintGasTest = 1;
    }
}
```

Note: the gas refund takes place *at the conclusion of the transaction*. Because of this, you may still hit the block gas limit if your transaction costs more than 8 million gas before the refund.