# Is the refund gas paid up-front?

Tags: yellow-paper, gas-refund

Excerpt from chapter 9 of the yellow paper, "Execution Model", describing the behaviour of the EMV when clearing storage:

> This refund is effectively paid up-front since the initial usage of a storage location costs substantially more than normal usage.

This seems to counteract this StackExchange [answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/3969/24693):

> The gas refund is provided only 1 time, at the very end of the transaction's execution.

I also know that the refunded gas is capped at half of the execution costs, so this is confusing. Does the first statement mean that the refund is actually **calculated** up-front (formally, in the σ checkpoint state transition) but only **transferred** to the caller after the execution is finished?

Comment: IMHO the wording is confusing. I read it as you already have paid the first time you set to non zero the slot, the refund is from that payment.