# Which are the operations providing gas refund available immediatly for the current running transaction?

Tags: gas, gas-refund

Most of gas refund operation aren’t available immediately, but instead increase the refund counter (which if I understand correctly is refunded not after the end of contract creation or call by contract but is instead refunded after the full end of the transaction).

I already found the 2300 stipend given for a transaction transferring funds… But is there anything else ?

Comment: AFAIK all refund operations are done at the end, and the 2300 gas stipend is unrelated to  refund operations.

Comment: @Ismael but like normal refunds it’s paid up‑front. I was meaning operation which behaves like the call stipend…

Comment: Gas stipend is the gas limit set by solidity compiler when you invoke transfer or send, it is not an extra cost over the regular CALL opcode used underneath.

Comment: @Ismael no. Calling a contract with a non zero value from an other contract involves an additional up‑front cost of 9000 gas (which is minored by the stipend in the child contract).