# Solidity: Paying contract deployment gas fees by calling selfdestruct on another contract

Tags: solidity, contract-development

I want to deploy a new contract. I have another contract with `kill()` function. Can I call `selfdestruct` on my new contract constructor and pay less gas fees? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `selfdestruct` refunds 24000 gas (https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/859/31933). I'm not sure how much gas is used by creating a reference to the other contract and calling its `kill` function, but probably you'll end up paying less.

This of course means that the contract to be self destroyed needs to first exist. Deploying such a contract will definitely cost more than 24000 gas - my very rough estimate is maybe 100000.

So, if you have in advance deployed a contract which can be self destroyed by you, you will possibly save a bit of gas by destroying the contract while deploying another contract (inside the constructor).

Comment: Thanks Lauri for your quick and complete answer