# Can a transaction have a negative fee?

Tags: gas, evm, fees, opcode

I know there are some opcodes that have negative gas costs (see [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/540/4938)). So if I send a transaction that calls one (or multiple) instance(s) of these opcodes, will the gas used be negative? i.e. will my balance increase?

Answer (score 3):

No, instructions that have negative gas can only reduce the other gas spent in the transaction. From the [yellow paper](https://ethereum.github.io/yellowpaper/paper.pdf):

[image: Gas refund up to half of gas spent]

A<sub>r</sub> is the sum of gas refunds across all refund instructions in the transaction. The refund is capped at half of the total gas spend.

Answer (score 0):

From the question you link to:

> The only two OPCODEs with negative gas costs are STORAGEKILL(-15000)
>   and GSUICIDEREFUND(-24000).
>
> These occur when storage values are deleted or contacts are suicided.

You will already have had to instantiate a contract on the blockchain for these calls to be relevant. That will cost you a certain (non-zero, positive) amount of gas.

When making these negative-gas calls you will get *part* of that original cost back. Overall you're still out of pocket.

Comment: You are right about the overall, but I just wonder what will happen for a single transaction, let's say, that will remove the data of five previous transactions.

Comment: Can't find STORAGEKILL opcode in the new sources, Richard

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question.

Unless I'm severely mistaken the answer is 'no'. From whom would the negative fee come?

The transaction itself has a cost in gas (fee). It is from this fee that the cost of negative opcodes is taken. The fee cannot be negative, otherwise, it would have to come from somewhere--and there's only two places it can come from--the winning miner for the current block (who is almost certainly a different miner than the one that won the block that set the data), or it would have to come out of nothing. Neither of those two things happen.